# Does anyone know what this piece of glassware is?

Tags: equipment

[image: unknown glassware]

I recently found this piece of lab glass with a jacket and spout. It says *eubilicmeter* but I cannot find any information about it online and I do not know what it is supposed to do.  It is hollow in the middle, sort of bell shaped. What is its name and what is it for?

Answer (score 22):

I believe this is an [ebulliometer](https://www.google.com/search?q=ebulliometer&biw=2560&bih=1437&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj70Nmk7PPPAhVLHT4KHaJEDrcQ_AUIBygC&dpr=1&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=PdNT6jBWd8QoqM%3A), from the Latin *[ebullientem](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ebullient&allowed_in_frame=0)* (to boil).

It's a used to measure boiling points. Clearly, there are some spelling issues with the sharpie label here.

Comment: Yes seems like that

Comment: Actually, this is a fun question to punt over to the Indoeuropean SE. :)

Comment: There might be fewer spelling errors that it first appears.  I'd say that the sharpie could be "eobiliometer" (allowing for handwriting, especially on a slick surface, and where it looks like some ink might have rubbed off), which only mistakes an "i" for a "ul".

Comment: It certainly was supposed to read  'ebulliometer', but the question is if it really is an ebulliometer? It does not look like one, maybe it's just a part of it. It is a vessel with double walls with vacuum in it (see that sealed tube at bottom right?). The central volume is thermally insulated - an ebulliometer must have a part that is heated, I don't see anything like that here.